# Nginx Server configuration for subdomains

Tags: configuration, nginx

I have a quick question about Nginx configuration. I am trying to setup multiple aliases for example 1.something.mydomain.com , 2.something.mydomain.com

When you include

```
 server_name something.mydomain.com
```

how is the matching done ? It seems as if Nginx will match `XXX.something.mydomain.com`  with the above.

Further to this is there a way to set up my DNS so that I can have one entry, I have seen that Regular expressions are supported in `NAPTR` records, but how do these point or relate to `A` records ?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [Server names](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) (nginx documentation).